# Conditional Formatting Code Crashing Program

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, countif, excel-2013

I have the following formulas as conditionals for a block of cells:

```
=COUNTIF(A:O, A3) = 2
=COUNTIF(A:O, A3) > 2
```

As I copy the conditions into more cells of the (A:O, 3:28) region, the program gets slower and slower and eventually stops responding. Is this a result of the conditionals, or some other cause, and is there a way to streamline the code to keep the program from crashing?

Comment: When you say "(A:O, 3:28)" do you mean the union of Column A to Column O (all rows) and Row 3 to Row 28 (all columns)? Or do you mean A3:O28?

Comment: @Jaycal: I meant (A:O U 3:28), so the whole block.

Comment: @pnuts: The code I have now is slowing the program, so I need to either limit the scope of the code or abbreviate it in some way in order to make it more efficient. Andy G makes a good point below; it's likely an effect of not having a row boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you intend to look explicitly in colums A to O, so you should use dollar-signs to fix the references:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$O,A3) = 2
=COUNTIF($A:$O,A3) > 2
```

Without these it will check from the current column, 14 columns to the right.

**Added** If your range that has the conditional formatting can be limited to a specific area then, assuming you first highlight the area A3:O50, then:

```
=COUNTIF($A$3:$O$50,A3) = 2
=COUNTIF($A$3:$O$50,A3) > 2
```

Comment: Do you really need to count the entire columns though? What about A1:O20000 ? I realise, though, that Excel is clever enough to realise that most of the column's cells are empty.

Comment: That's a good point; I didn't realize that the formula would be checking the entire column. I only need the first 30 rows or so. How do I limit the region in the formula?

Comment: Also, to address the first part of the answer, I do need every column to be checked. This is in order to compare lists of object identifiers. If the object id shows up once, it has one status, twice a different status, and a third time means its transaction is complete. We need to find which objects are in which state.

Comment: I've added to my answer.